# Verbose text log output to .txt

Tags: powershell

I know this is simple to most of you but I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

```
cd c:\
$item = '123'
Rename-Item $item -NewName '2019' -Verbose
Write-Verbose "Success" -Verbose >> c:\temp\test.txt
```

When I open the test.txt it is empty. How would you log the verbose message that you see here into a .txt?

[image]

Comment: The verbose stream is 4. `Write-Verbose "Success" -Verbose 4>> c:\temp\test.txt`

Comment: What I am really after is that first VERBOSE message. Anything you add in the "" is a message regardless of the action fails or not (in this case renaming the item). Even when I ran this script and the folder are not there essentially Powershell will give you an error that folder does not exist, I want to capture that message Dynamically. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you want to capture all streams including error and verbose, you can use `*>>`. You can check against the `$?` variable, which will output true if the previous command was successful. Then you can make a custom message based on that: `if ($?) { write-verbose "Success" -Verbose } else { write-verbose "Failed" -verbose }` as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default (`>`) outputs the success stream (`1`). You can access a specific stream by prepending the corresponding stream number to the `>`. You can also redirect a particular stream to the success stream with the syntax (`n>&1 > file.txt`) where `n` is the stream number. Multiple streams can be redirected at once like error and verbose (`6>&1 4>&1 > file.txt`). For all streams, the wildcard character can be used in place of `n` (`*>`).

An alternative approach is just to use `try-catch-finally` blocks for error catching and then performing actions based on error conditions.

Here is a basic example of verbose stream redirection (`4>>`) and all streams (`*>>`) with error checking. The `$?` returns true if the previously run command was successful.

**Example 1: `Rename-Item` has an error.**

```
rename-item verb1.txt verb2.txt -verbose *>> verbose.txt
if ($?) { 
   write-verbose "Rename-Item Was Successful" -Verbose 4>> verbose.txt }
else { 
   Write-Verbose "Rename-Item Failed" -Verbose 4>> verbose.txt }
Get-Content verbose.txt
```

> rename-item : Cannot rename because item at 'verb1.txt' does not
>   exist. At line:1 char:1
>   + rename-item verb1.txt verb2.txt -verbose *>> verbose.txt
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
>
> Rename-Item Failed

**Example 2: `Rename-Item` has no error.**

```
rename-item verb2.txt verb1.txt -verbose *>> verbose.txt
if ($?) { 
   write-verbose "Rename-Item Was Successful" -Verbose 4>> verbose.txt }
else { 
   Write-Verbose "Rename-Item Failed" -Verbose 4>> verbose.txt }

Get-Content verbose.txt
```

> Performing the operation "Rename File" on target
>   "Item: verb2.txt Destination: verb1.txt".
>   Rename-Item Was Successful

See [About_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) for more details.